# SQL/JAVA Communications link error occasionally happens JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

experiencing this error, If someone could use the code I provided to fix it in their answer that would be great. I'm not good with SQL I'm just helping out a friend.

Here is the code:

```
public static Connection con = null;
public static Statement stmt;
public static boolean connectionMade;
public static void createConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/highscores","root","root");
        stmt = con.createStatement();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static ResultSet query(String s) throws SQLException {
    try {
        if (s.toLowerCase().startsWith("select")) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(s);
            return rs;
        } else {
            stmt.executeUpdate(s);
        }
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        destroyConnection();
        createConnection();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
public static void destroyConnection() {
    try {
        if(stmt != null)
        stmt.close();
        if(con!= null)
        con.close();
        connectionMade = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

full stack trace:

```
[9/07/15 19:23]: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 10 ms ago.
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2871)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3414)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2536)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1564)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1485)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.util.SQL.query(SQL.java:29)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.util.SQL.saveHighScore(SQL.java:55)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.model.mobile.players.Client.logout(Client.java:581)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.model.mobile.players.packets.Clicking.ClickingButtons.processPacket(ClickingButtons.java:2190)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.model.mobile.players.PacketHandler.processPacket(PacketHandler.java:118)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.model.mobile.players.Client.processQueuedPackets(Client.java:769)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.model.mobile.players.PlayerHandler.process(PlayerHandler.java:191)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.Server$1.execute(Server.java:103)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.task.Task2.tick(Task2.java:105)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.event.TaskScheduler.run(TaskScheduler.java:100)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]: Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2431)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2882)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        ... 24 more
[9/07/15 19:23]: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Last packet sent to the server was 10 ms ago.
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2871)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3414)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2536)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1564)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1485)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.util.SQL.query(SQL.java:29)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.util.SQL.saveHighScore(SQL.java:55)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.model.mobile.players.Client.logout(Client.java:581)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.model.mobile.players.packets.Clicking.ClickingButtons.processPacket(ClickingButtons.java:2190)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.model.mobile.players.PacketHandler.processPacket(PacketHandler.java:118)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.model.mobile.players.Client.processQueuedPackets(Client.java:769)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.model.mobile.players.PlayerHandler.process(PlayerHandler.java:191)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.Server$1.execute(Server.java:103)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.task.Task2.tick(Task2.java:105)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at server.event.TaskScheduler.run(TaskScheduler.java:100)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[9/07/15 19:23]: Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2431)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2882)
[9/07/15 19:23]:        ... 24 more
```

Comment: The root cause seems to `java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.`. Maybe [this can help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950496/what-is-java-io-eofexception-message-can-not-read-response-from-server-expect)

Comment: Since `createConnection` doesn't appear in the stack trace, it's possible that you're using a stale `Connection` which has already been closed...

Comment: What can I do to fix it? @MadProgrammer

Comment: Rather then doing `stmt = con.createStatement();` this in `createConnection`, create a `stmt` each time you need it from active connection (and make you close it when you're done).  Also you can use `Connection#isClosed` and `Connection#isValid` to test the connection and recreate it as required.  You might also consider using a `ConnectionPool` of some kind to take care of this automatically for you

Comment: Can you show that with the code I provided? Sorry i'm not great at this just doing it for my friend. It is for an automatic system. @MadProgrammer

Comment: Not really, the code you've provided is only part of the problem

Comment: I added the rest of the connection code just now. @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, it appears that the `Connection` and `Statement` which you are relying has been closed, either explicitly be yourself or implicitly by the server.

As a general good practice, you should be creating a new `Statement` only when you need it and closing it when you're doing, for example...

```
public Connection createConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/highscores", "root", "root");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
        throw new SQLException("Unable to load JDBC driver", ex);
    }
    return con;
}

public void makeQuery() throws SQLException {

    try (Connection con = createConnection()) {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("...")) {
            // Fill in parameters to the statement
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    // Get the results
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Good practice would also suggest that you make use of `PreparedStatement`s to ensure that you code doesn't fall victim to SQL inject attacks

Have a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details.

I would also encourage you to do some research into connection pools, as it will help save you time when creating multiple connections and help manage their life cycle.

I'd also beware of using `static`, as this raises the risk of threading issues, having one thread close the connection while another thread is trying to use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My code is now in line with your suggestions (however messy) and it seems to be working well. @MadProgrammer